# Prove that $f$ is an identification

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

This question is from the third edition of Bert Mendelson's "Introduction to Topology". The following is exercise number six of section two, chapter five (on page 164).

**Problem Statement:** Let $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous function of a compact space $X$ *onto* a Hausdorff space $Y$. Prove that $f$ is an identification.

**Definition of an Identification Mapping:** Let $p:E \to B$ be a continuous mapping from a topological space $E$ onto the topological space $B$. $p$ is called an *identification* if for each subset $U$ of $B$, $p^{-1}(U)$ open in $E$ implies $U$ is open in $B$.

Following are some useful lemmas (which are given in the book as theorems).

**Lemma L1:** Let $X$ be a compact topological space. Then each closed subset of $X$ is compact.

**Lemma L2:** Let $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous function and let $A$ be a compact subset of $X$. Then $f(A)$ is a compact subset of $Y$.

**Lemma L3:** Let $Y$ be a Hausdorff space. If a subset $F$ of $Y$ is compact, then $F$ is closed.

**My thought process:** Let $O \subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in X. Hence $X-f^{-1}(O)$ is closed in $X$. As $f^{-1}(Y-O) = X-f^{-1}(O)$, we have that $f^{-1}(Y-O)$ is closed in $X$. Using **L1**, we have that $f^{-1}(Y-O)$ is compact in $X$. Using **L2**, we have that $f(f^{-1}(Y-O))$ is compact in $Y$. Using **L3**, we can conclude that $f(f^{-1}(Y-O))$ is closed in $Y$.

Now $f(f^{-1}(Y-O)) = Y-O$ as $f$ is onto. Hence $O$ is open in $Y$ as desired. Please let me know if my proof is correct and if not, please point me to the errors.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the confirmation!